# Query DOL VETS4212 Database with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to query the DOL VETS4212 Database with Python (https://developer.dol.gov/others/vets4212/).  My ultimate objective is to extract the data for specific companies (company names are listed under either 'CoName' or 'HlName').  However, I'm having trouble with even a basic query.  I've tried the following, without success:

```
    APIKey = '40_Digit_APIkey'

    url = 'https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json'
    token = '36_Character_Token'

    #parameters = {'CoName': 'Baker McKenzie'}

    username1 = 'username@yahoo.com/36_Character_Token'
    username2 = 'username' 
    password = 'password'

    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(username, token))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=('', token))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(username2, password))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(token, ''))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(username, ''))  
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(APIKey, ''))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(APIKey, token))
    #response= requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=('', APIKey))
    #response= requests.get(url, auth=('', APIKey))
    response= requests.get(url, auth=(APIKey, ''))

    print(response.status_code)

    response.content.decode("utf-8")
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you haven't used limit param which is a mandatory param.

```
curl -k -H "X-API-KEY:<your api key > " https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/10
```

update: I looked at python library requests and looks like you can make the call like this

```
requests.get('https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/10', headers = {'X-API-KEY':'YOURAPIKEYHERE'})
```